# Dual boot with Windows 7 issue: Windows occasionally restarts at startup

Tags: windows

The installation went smooth and everything works fine with Ubuntu. The issue is as follows:
When I boot into Windows 7, it shows the Windows logo and start loading and suddenly restarts. Luckily, this does not happen always, after a few restarts it does startup properly.
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Did such behavior happen before installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try to schedule a disk check when you are able to boot or press F8 for the Windows boot menu and boot in safe mode.

You can schedule a disk check by pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys and typing `chkdsk /F`.

Answer (score 1):

All modern operating systems (Windows7, the 'buntus, etc) do error-check-repair when booting. What is happening in your case is normal.

Eventually, after about two Windows7 reboots, it accepts that there is another operating system on the computer. If it contines to give the message: " ... press any key if you do not want ..." to error check, then stop it from further error checking.  If you watch the error checks, you will see they it detects no further errors, but continues with its silly nag-screens.

Only rarely do I use Win7 now, but when I do, Win7 hates things that Linux tolerates, like filenames with " ? ! ... ; in their filenames. That is mainly what Win7 is complaining.  Occasionally it does have a real gripe. So I let Win7 do its NTFS file system check.  When it finds 'errors', it creates a directory called dirxxx, with many files names filexxx.chk. Some of these filexxx.chk are zero files, so I delete these. Under 1 kilobyte - delete these.  Others are renamed to filesxxx.txt, then (sometimes) examined to put the correct extension on them.

Sometimes I seemingly lose work, since all my data, archives, temp, cache, etc are on NTFS-compressed partitions & files. But regular backups, and easily tracable work tracking, I avoid losing my work & data.